# Angular JS - Identifying type of isolated category in child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, tabs, scope

I have a custom directive with isolated scope for category :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myModule').directive('myContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myContent.html',
    scope: {
        category: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      // private methods
    },
    controllerAs: 'myContentCtrl'
  };
});
```

In my main directive am calling the same directive as  :

```
<div>
      <my-content category = "category1"></my-content>
</div>

<div>
     <my-content category = "category2"></my-content>
</div>

<div>
     <my-content category = "category3"></my-content>
</div>
```

And myContent.html is having :

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 navbar">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active itemFirst"><a href="#link1" role="tab"
                                                data-toggle="tab">Link 1 </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#link2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Link 2 </a></li>
                <li><a href="#link3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Link 3 </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="link1">
                // contents here for link 1
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="link2">
                // contents here for link 2
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="link3">
                // contents here for link 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here my issue is, the id is getting replicating as the same direct is populating each links. 
So the UI is not populating the different directives and tabs properly.

How can I separate the Id of each one by identifying the category value I had send to each directive.

My requirement is making id dynamic as :

```
id = "link1_{{category}}"
```

But it is not reflecting. How can I achieve this?

Updating the category object.

My category objects are having some data like :

```
$scope.category1 = [
     {obj1},
     {obj2},
     {obj3},
     {obj4}
];
$scope.category2 = [
     {obj1},
     {obj2},
     {obj3},
     {obj4}
];
```

So I can't use category1 object as an ID. instead how can i use the string "category1" that I'm separating each categories. I hope now the code is clear.

Comment: Just to be sure: `category1`, `category2`, … are scope variables, right?

Comment: yeah. But I need only the string that I'm passing. "category1"

Comment: Do you need different ids for each `<div>` for all instances of `<my-content>` directive .

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just resolved it in a complicated approach, but am not sure about the perfection.

I had added one more data in category object as "type"
Now my category object is:

```
$scope.category1 = {
       type : "category1",
       data : [
              {obj1},
              {obj2},
              {obj3},
              {obj4}
       ]
};
$scope.category2 = {
       type : "category2",
       data : [
              {obj1},
              {obj2},
              {obj3},
              {obj4}
       ]
};
```

So in HTML the id is :

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 navbar">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active itemFirst"><a href="#{{category.type}}" role="tab"
                                                    data-toggle="tab">Link 1 </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#{{category.type}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Link 2 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#{{category.type}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Link 3 </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="{{category.type}}">
                    // contents here for link 1
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="{{category.type}}">
                    // contents here for link 2
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="{{category.type}}">
                    // contents here for link 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same: to change the structure of your objects. Nice work. However, with current code, you would end up with three `<div>` having same `id` which fall within the same category

Answer (score 1):

I think you need different ID for each `<div>` for all instances of directive.

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id={{'link1_'+category}}></div>
```

and use `@` in isolated scope to get values of attributes

```
app.directive('myContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myContent.html',
    scope: {
        category : '@'
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      // private methods
      console.log($scope.category)
    },
    controllerAs: 'myContentCtrl'
  };
});
```

Here's the working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2MrZBH5zmZpKnioM5njn?p=preview)

Comment: I need the category object as isolated scope, and is having some data. How can I get the string "category1", if am using category : '@', the model object is not reflecting.

Comment: Aren't the ID's of `<div>` in myContent.html getting the values of respective `category` (`category1` for first directive, `category2` for second directive and so on..)?

Comment: Please have a  look at demo and inspect respective elements.

Comment: do you want to retain  two-way binding ?

Comment: yeah, pls have a look on the category objects now  added in the question. I hope it might be little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, You can set the Id in a function inside your controller...

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="{{setId}}">
```

And in your custom directive with isolated scope for category :

```
controller: function($scope){
    // private methods
    $scope.setId = function(){...}
},
```